# boot2docker fails to start on windows 7

Tags: docker, windows-7-x64, boot2docker

I recently installed `boot2docker` on my `windows 7 64bit` machine with all dependencies (`VirtualBox` etc). However, when I executed it, it failed to start the docker server and preconfigured shell. From the cmd I could read the following exception:

```
Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was the **disabled virtualization**. I found this by running `VirtualBox` and trying to manually boot the "boot2docker-vm" vitual machine. You can usually enable virtualization from the `BIOS` under CPU or Security settings. If you are not sure if your mache supports virtualization you can check it by using something like [speccy](http://speccy.com).

Comment: speccy: in the CPU section, `Virtualization Supported, Enabled`