# Windows Boot2Docker VM producing unknown software exception

Tags: windows, virtualbox, boot2docker

I have a fresh install of VirtualBox and Boot2Docker on my Windows 8.1 machine. When I try to run `start.sh` from the Boot2Docker install, I get the following message.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if desactiving the anti-virus improves things? Does your BIOS has the Virtualization enabled? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29963272/6309)

Comment: I can't deactivate anti-virus on my work PC and yes visualization is enabled in the BIOS. I had VMWare running (now uninstalled to reduce conflicts) and I have a working VBox VM outside of Boot2Docker

Comment: Ok. I used VirtualBox myself (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309)